# jQuery click onto div trigger, child div triggers it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So when a user clicks onto the div popu it does trigger the hide(), which is good, but when I click on the text, it does close but I want it to stay open.

HTML:

```
<div id="s" class="popu"><img class="tri" src="img/whtri.png"/>
    <div class="textb"><center style="font-size:14px;">Item Title</center>
        <span style="font-size:12px;">Description this is an item that is very good and i like it very much! I like <a href="f.php">More...</a>
        </span>
        <span style="">
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT/JQUERY:

```
$("body").click(function (e) {
        if (!$(e.target).hasClass("popu")) {
            $("#s").hide(200)
        }
    })
```

**Keep in mind this is a snippet of code**

Any Help Would Be Awesome!

Comment: *clicks onto the div popu* how can you do this? it makes no sense, the div is just a container, it contains an image, a link, some text so what exactly do you click on?

Comment: So, what you want is when clicking the `popu` div `#s` is hidden, but when clicking anything within the `popu` div, `#s` is not hidden?

Comment: The accepted answer does not seem to accomplish that. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cNTHt/2/)

Comment: @DerekS - That's because you didn't give the body a size, so you're not clicking the body, and then nothing works. In other words, you're assuming the OP has the same set up as jsFiddle, with a no-size body, but most people would use a CSS reset that fixes this.

Comment: I will note that I would probably target the document instead, as it would be more reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't just check for the class on the clicked element, it will fail when clicking any children of the element, check if *any parent* or the clicked element has the class, which can be done with `closest()`

```
$("body").click(function (e) {
    if (!$(e.target).closest(".popu").length) {
        $("#s").hide(200)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with this -

```
$(".tri").click(function (e) {
    if( $(this).parent().hasClass('popu') ){
        $("#s").hide(200)
    }
})
```

Test for a click on the image, find out if the parent has the right class, then hide if appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `#s` is hide only when clicking on the popu div, but when clicking anything within the popu div, #s is not hide.

Try to remove `not` OR `!` .

```
$("body").click(function (e) {
        if ($(e.target).hasClass("popu")) {
            $("#s").hide(200)
        }
    })
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rd8f6/)